# ListView item "don't want be a selected" getSelectedItemPosition return -1

Tags: android, listview, sdk, selected

I want to get SelectedItem index of ListView. I select item by tapping on item. OnItemClick event work fine, but getSelectedItemPosition() return -1.

What I do wrong?

xml:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvAddEdtList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:listSelector="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle" />
```

In Activity:

```
 lvAddEdtDel.setAdapter(namesList);
 lvAddEdtDel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            lvAddEdtDel.setSelection(position);
            view.setSelected(true);

        }
    });
```

---

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(lvAddEdtDel.getSelectedItemPosition() < 0 )
{ 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.ItemNotSelected),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
}
});
```

sorry for my English

Comment: try to compare it with list view length.

Comment: I don't understand why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. 
Layout of the adapter has chosen: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

In my case, it was necessary to choose: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice;

In touch mode must yuse getCheckedItemPosition